# My assembler code has this error: "invalid program counter value: 0x00000000 Go: execution terminated with errors"

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

```
.data
    prompt2: .asciiz "please enter the elements one by one:"
    prompt3: .asciiz "the array is ordered as follows: "
    prompt4: .asciiz "-- Program is finished running --"
    str1: .asciiz ","
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
.text

    addi $sp,$sp,-24
    sw $ra,0($sp)
    sw $s4,4($sp)
    sw $a2,8($sp)
    sw $s3,12($sp)
    sw $s0,16($sp)
    sw $s2,20($sp)
main:


    # read n from console
    li $v0 5
    syscall

    move $a2 $v0    #tagghiir t0 be a2 (n)

   # allocate dynamic memory
    sll $a0 $v0 2    # sll performs $a0 = $v0 x 2^2
    li $v0 9    #9 is the system code for service(sbrk) whoes work is        
    syscall     #to allocate dynamic memory


    move $a1 $v0 #t2 saved address of heap    #taghiir t2 to a1
  #saved for printing


    li $v0, 4       # $system call code for print_str
    la $a0, prompt2     # $address of string to print
    syscall  

    move $t1 $zero
    move $t4,$a1

    inputLoop:
        bge $t1 $a2 exit1

        # read in and store int
        li $v0 5
        syscall
        sw $v0 0($t4)

        addi $t1 $t1 1
        addi $t4 $t4 4

        li $v0, 4       # $system call code for print_str
        la $a0, newLine     # $address of string to print
        syscall

        j inputLoop

    exit1:

    jal sort
    li $v0, 4       # $system call code for print_str
    la $a0, prompt3     # $address of string to print
    syscall

    move $t3,$zero
    move $t4 ,$a1
    outputLoop:
        bge $t3 $a2 exit2

        #inaro azoon yki copy krdm
        lw $t6, 0($t4)

        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t6
        syscall
        # read in and store int
        addi $t3 $t3 1
        addi $t4 $t4 4
        blt $t4,$a1 ,comma
       # bne $t5,$zero,comma
        comma:
            li $v0, 4       # $system call code for print_str
            la $a0, str1     # $address of string to print
            syscall
        j outputLoop

    exit2:

    li $v0, 10
    syscall    #for finishing the program

swap:


    move  $a3,$a3
    move  $a1,$s4
   # move $t5,$zero # its for our temp variable in c code
    move $t4 ,$a1 #t4 is now the base address of heap
    sll $t6 , $a3,2 # s1 is the given k 
    add $t6,$t4,$t6 # heap address + k*4
    lw $t3,0($t6) #khoone k e heap
    lw $t5,4($t6) #khoone k+1 heap
    sw $t5,0($t6)
    sw $t3,4($t6)
    jr $ra 




sort:


  #  move $s0,$zero #i=t0
    move $s4,$a1 #base address of heap
    addi $t5,$a2,-1 # meghdare i

    move $s2,$zero #its the flag

    while:
        addi $s2,$s2,1
        move $a3,$zero #j   #taghiir s1 be a3 (haman j va k
        forLoop:

            bge $a3,$t5,outOfLoop
            sll $t6,$a3,2    #j  
            add $t1,$t6,$a1 #v+j
            lw $t7,0($t1) #t7=heap[j]
            lw $t8,4($t1) #t8=heap[j+1]
            blt $t7,$t8,outOfIf
            move $s4,$a1
            move $s3,$a3

            jal swap
            addi $s2,$s2,-1
        outOfIf:
        addi $a3,$a3,1   #j++
        outOfLoop:
        addi $t5,$t5-1 #i--
        bgt $s2,$zero,exit_outter   #if a>=b break
        ble $t5,$zero,exit_outter   #if b=< c break
        j while

     exit_outter:
     lw $ra,0($sp)
     lw $s4,4($sp)
     lw $a2,8($sp)
     lw $s3,12($sp)
     lw $s0,16($sp)
     lw $s2,20($sp)
     addi $sp,$sp,24
     jr $ra
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What line do you get this error on? Have you done any debugging to find out what intermediate logic or calculations is going wrong?

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it line by line in the debugger. After each instruction, compare what you have with what you expect. Pay particular attention to the `jr` instructions, since those are the ones that can cause the program counter to transfer to a computed address.

Comment: well im new to mips but i did debug and when it goes to the last lines and lw everything from stack its values chaanges to 0 i guess and it does not turn back to the main as i expect.. i dunno what to do cuz when i change the place of load words from stack i dont get any result again..

Comment: I've repaired the code formatting in this question once already - would you fix it this time? I cannot keep doing so. Use triple backticks on their own line, one at the start of the code, one at the end. Do not publish anything where you have not checked the post using the preview window first.

Comment: i dunno how to do that tbh D: why does it annoy u bro? D;

Comment: btw i fixed da code D; so i dont think if i should repair it, i dunno